# I keep getting this error when i want to query data from a model in mysql database : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is the model I'm working with

```
class Lga(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lga_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entered_by_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField()
    user_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lga'
```

This is the code from my Django shell

```
from Inec_results.models import PollingUnit, Lga
local = Lga.objects.all()   
print(local)
```

And I get this error all the time I try to query that model. I'm new to Django please help me out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __repr__    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__ 
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 68, in __iter__ 
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1149, in 
apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\operations.py", line 311, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 262, in make_aware
    if is_aware(value):
  File "C:\Users\olaniran\.virtualenvs\BincomDev-TkuS52cz\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 228, in is_aware 
    return value.utcoffset() is not None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py makemmigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after making model changes?

Comment: @IainShelvington yeah i did so and it still gives me an error t

Comment: What version/flavour of MySQL is your DB, what version of mysqlconnector are you using and what version of Python/Django?

Comment: @IainShelvington python == 3.8, Django=4.0, MySQL = 8.0.27 and i'm serving the database from mySQL workbench

Comment: Can you share your `Lga` model? Maybe you have some naive date defaults defined.

Comment: ` 
class Lga(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lga_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entered_by_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField()
    user_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lga' `

Comment: @Marco that the model

Comment: Please just update your initial question with the model. But unfortunately, I can't see any naive date defaults.

Comment: @Marco I just update the question with the model..... oops I'm still confused as to what might be the problem. serving the database with MySQL workbench

Comment: Try to set a default to your `date_entered` field (e.g. to `django.utils.timezone.now`), or set its `auto_now_add` parameter to `True`.

Comment: Since the model is not managed it could also be that the data definition in the db of date_entered is without timezone. @Myekini can you share the data definition of `date_entered` of your database?

Comment: Head to your mysql terminal and try to query the table `select * from lga;` and see if it works there if yes then the issue could be cased by `managed=False`

Comment: @Ahtisham I actually queried the model from the MySQL terminal and it works. I also removed the `managed=False` and I still get the error

Comment: @JordanBrière even after adding `auto_now_add` parameter to `True` i still get same error

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate after removing managed=false?

Comment: @marco i did absolutely.. but still.....

Comment: I found a solution, guys. it seems as though the information wasn't properly queried from the database. so I uninstalled the MySQL server and configured it from scratch. likewise, I also tried the XAMPP server and it queried the database properly

Answer (score 1):

hello sorry this was answered late, I was experiencing this issue today and this was how i fixed it.

go to the settings.py file and set the USE_TZ to False.

USE_TZ = False

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks so much. I also later figured it out and this was what worked for me as well